# Aligning the last column of a table using CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net, css-tables

I have a bunch of data input screens and they all use a basic table filled with asp.net textboxes. Some of the textboxes (the smallest ones) are set to 250px in width. The others have been set a width in px depending on what makes them align best at 100% zoom.

The issue is when you zoom in and out, it's clear that the boxes don't really line up on the far right.

Can anyone suggest a way to properly align these last columns. It's worth noting that for some reason when using 100% in the last column that it busts outside of the actual table a certain way for unknown reasons.

The columns with the larger textboxes are defined using colspan of 2 or 3.

The boxes at 100%
[image: 100 percent]
The boxes at 75%
[image: 75 percent]

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? Maybe some css code may help...

Comment: Could we see this in something like jsfiddle please?

Comment: The CSS is mixed in with a mass of other styles. I was kind of hoping someone would identify this as a common issue. To make things more difficult the mis-alignment seems more prominent in Chrome than in other browsers.